# vccw - How can I set the xdebug.remote_host?

Tags: vagrant

I'm using `vccw` which is in turn **Wordpress on Vagrant**.
For debugging I need to set `xdebug.remote_host` to  `10.0.2.2`.
If I change it in the `php.ini` file it is ignored.
The default value in `default.yml` is wrong.

How can I set the `xdebug.remote_host`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, you will be able to find your happiness : 
https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2016/08/configure-xdebug-phpstorm-vagrant/

Answer (score 0):

1. vagrant ssh
2. sudo vi /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/99-vccw.ini
3. set the the value in line `xdebug.remote_host` , save, exit
4. sudo service apache2 restart